# Throw error on task scheduler when python script throws error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have a python script. I have scheduled it to run monthly on Windows scheduler. However, it is prone to error sometimes and I would like to know if it threw an error. However the windows scheduler always shows the status as Successful. How can I make the Windows scheduler display the error or notify me if my .py script throws an error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can show the information in Windows scheduler because it calls `ShellExecuteEx()` to run your program and that will report success no matter what return code your Python program issues. That is because the scheduler has successfully run the Python interpreter, which is all it cares about.

Have your program write the error to the Windows event log and look for it there. You can get fancy and set up the event log to notify you.

Comment: `ShellExecuteEx` can return process handle to wait on and get the exit code, but that's not the issue because the task scheduler actually calls `LogonUserExExW` or `LsaLogonUser` (S4U) combined with `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Comment: The OP doesn't say, but I think this problem is for an older version of the task scheduler. In Windows 10 it keeps the process handle and shows the process exit code. IIRC, in Windows 7 it only reports whether or not it successfully started the task.

Comment: @eryksun I am using Windows 10, it doesn't show the process exit code for me. I tried it out with a simple python script containing print a. It throws a NameError but when I run it with the scheduler, it tells me that the task ran successfully. I understand that the task scheduler has nothing to do with checking whether the script ran successfully or not. It only bothers with whether it ran or not. But there has got to be a way to make the scheduler tell me that or at least my python code to tell me that.

Comment: @glitterati, what exactly are you running for the action?

Comment: @eryksun I've tried using the win32evtlog to log an event.

Comment: @glitterati, I meant the command you're running. Are you trying to run the .py script directly? Don't do that. In that case it runs it via OpenWith.exe, which is basically going to shell execute it. Run the script via either the fully-qualified path for python.exe or py.exe, and pass the path to the script as the argument. In this case the task scheduler will call `CreateProcessAsUser` and have a handle it can wait on and get the exit code.

Comment: @glitterati, strike that. When I tried to schedule a .py script directly I made the mistake of setting the path in quotes. That's why it resorted to OpenWith.exe. When I removed the quotes around the path, it worked fine. In a debugger attached to the scheduler's svchost.exe host process, I can see that it uses shell APIs to resolve the executable path to run without actually asking the shell to run it. Instead it passes the command line to `CreateProcessAsUser`. Thus even running a .py script directly will get the process exit code.