# Windows Scheduler - display error on python script failure

Tags: python, windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have similar issue like [one from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754488/throw-error-on-task-scheduler-when-python-script-throws-error) - I have a python script which I'd like to run and should it fail (by calling `exit(<value different than 0>`), display error in the Windows Scheduler Task History window.
From the comments I understood that it actually is doable somehow - you can get python process exit code. I'm wondering can I somehow make scheduler display non-zero return codes as failures?

I tried running a `.bat` file wrapping the python script and setting the error code (`exit \b 123`) but again - this does not solve the issue.

[image: last run result]

[image: error instead of information]

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a control script that is run by the scheduler after the main one, and its launch depends on - "did the main script fail?".

Comment: Seems over complicated and to be honest I am not really interested in workarounds. For another task (.net program) it reports failures correctly, so it must be something due to how python works and propagates results/exit codes. By the way I tried building exe using pyinstaller but it also does not show as failure in the Task Scheduler, neither on non-zero exit code nor on uncaught exception.